# VBA Buttons that can Move?

Tags: excel, vba, form-control, radio-button

I am running into a wall when it comes to adding buttons in VBA.

I have a spreadsheet that could potentially have rows expanded or have rows added to it. Right now, the only way I know how to add buttons with a macro (i.e. when you click this button, three more buttons appear below) is with the coordinate system

```
With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(185, 464, 72, 18)
    .Name = "firstcheckbox"
    .Caption = "CLICK ME"
End With
```

However, if someone adds rows above in the form BEFORE they click the button-making button, those coordinates are no longer good and the three buttons show up higher than I'd like them.

I've wracked my brain trying to research this. Is there some obvious way to create these buttons with a cell instead of coordinates so that it doesn't matter how many rows are added above?

```
With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add.Range("C6")
    .Name = "firstcheckbox"
    .Caption = "CLICK ME"
End With
```

or something like that? Or am I limited to the coordinate system?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the `Left` and `Top` properties from the Range, then pass them to `Checkboxes.Add`:

```
With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(Range("C6").Left, Range("C6").Top, 72, 18)
    .Name = "firstcheckbox"
    .Caption = "CLICK ME"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess this still gives me the issue of said cell changing when a row is added anyway, but seriously this issue has plagued me for a loooooong time.